# Como intercalar valores de listas en un print

Tags: python, lista

Tengo dos listas transformadas a strings con el método `(' '.join(map(str, list1)))` y `(' '.join(map(str, list2)))`.

El contenido de cada una es:

```
list1: [1,2,3]
list2: ['A','B','C']
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es intercalar un print con otro, es decir, imprimir `1A, 2B, 3C`.

Es posible hacer esto con las listas "transformadas" a strings? Gracias.

Comment: `[A, B, C]` no puede ser una definición válida, lo mismo querrías `["A", "B", "C"]`. ¿Has investigado un poco? Como pista, existe `zip` para hacer este tipo de cosas...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' y es posible imprimir el resultado de un zip, sin los paréntesis y las comillas ? (ya he usado el join y sigue saliendo con paréntesis y comillas)

Comment: muestra lo que intentaste con `join` y así sabremos en qué punto estás

Comment: con un simple `for k,v in zip(l1,l2): print(k,v, sep="")` se ve bastante bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Es posible hacer esto con las listas "transformadas" a strings?*
Si, es posible.

Como imagino que estás estudiando, voy a enseñarte la que creo que es la manera más *fácil* de resolverlo:

```py
# En python, los strings pueden ser cortados/accedidos como si fuesen una lista!
frase = "Hola mundo!"
# Esto imprimirá solo los 4 primeros caracteres de la variable
print(frase[0:4])

# Y esto imprimirá toda la frase, pero letra a letra
for i in range(0, len(frase)):
    print(frase[i])

# Con un loop de ese estilo podrás hacer lo que necesitas. Tan solo queda una cosita...
# Dices que quieres imprimir ambos juntos, qué tal si usamos format para ello?
for i in range(0, len(frase)):
    # El método format() acepta tantos parámetros como símbolos {} haya en el string!
    print("La letra en la posicion {} es: {}".format(i, frase[i]))
    # Esto nos imprimirá La letra en la posicion 0 es: H, y así con todas las letras!
```

También podrías imprimirlo sin usar `format()`, pero *creo* que es una manera un poco más correcta de hacerlo y seguro que te vendrá bien para el futuro.

Te he dejado las explicaciones en los comentarios. Suerte con el ejercicio!